# Im having issue. Grade variable may not have been initialized... im learning JOptionPane sorry.

Tags: java, variables

```
//************************************************************
//  Grade.java  Lawrence Maizon-Taylor
//  Gives response based on inputed grade
//************************************************************

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Grade
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String name, gradeString;
        int grade; //variable

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "This program asks for your name and number based on a pass or fail grade of a course"); //makes statement
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter your first name: "); //asks for name
        gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter a number 1 if you passed the course or a number 2 if you failed the course: ");//asks for number based on grade

        if (grade == 1)
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, name + " congratulations on passing the course!");
        else
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, name + " sorry you didn't pass. Next time study!");

        grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);

        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

this is literally pissing me off. I'm getting an error message from the compiler stating that the variable grade may not be initialized and I don't know what I'm supposed to do

Comment: You never assign an initial value to `grade` so when it comes to `if (grade == 1)` it doesn't know what to do

Comment: Initialize it with default value: int grade = 0;

Comment: @Nemus Based on what the OP's code is doing, that would void the `if-else` statement, better to move the conversion of `gradeString` above the `if-else` statement

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do what it said!

```
int grade = 0;
```

Also you will need to move your `parseInt` above before checking if the value matches

Comment: Which would void the OP's `if-else` statement

Answer (score 0):

You never assign an initial value to `grade` so when it comes to `if (grade == 1)` it doesn't know what to do

The problem is, you're trying to compare the state of the value before you've assigned a value to it (local variables are not assigned a default value)

If you simply took `grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);` and moved it above the `if-else` statement, it would solve your problem and make more logical sense

```
public class Grade
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String name, gradeString;
        int grade; //variable

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "This program asks for your name and number based on a pass or fail grade of a course"); //makes statement
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter your first name: "); //asks for name
        gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter a number 1 if you passed the course or a number 2 if you failed the course: ");//asks for number based on grade

        grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);

        if (grade == 1)
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, name + " congratulations on passing the course!");
        else
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, name + " sorry you didn't pass. Next time study!");

        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: further last `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` in `if-else` section does not make sense .

Comment: @sakhunzai Why? if `1` it displays congratulations, else it it's assumed you didn't pass, sure, should probably be checking for `0`, but considering that `Integer.parseInt` will also want to throw an exception which is currently not handled, I was focusing purely on solving the OPs problem, before they were encouraged to set the initial value of `grade` to `0` and threw the entire `if-else` block out the window - don't want to solve ALL the OPs problems ;)

Comment: I meant it should be something like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` instead of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` since we are not collecting input  at the end. Your argument is correct otherwise

Comment: @sakhunzai Ahh, good point, guess I'll worry about that on there next question ;P